# Hi I am working on a Java insertion question right now, and a type of error appears after my codes ran; dunno how to solve it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

here are the question and my code:
Create a public non-final class called `InsertionSorter`. It should provide one public class method called sort. Sort should accept an array of Comparable Java objects and sort them in ascending order. However, it should sort the array in place, meaning that you modify the original array, and return the number of swaps required to sort the array. That’s how we’ll know you’ve correctly implemented insertion sort. If the array is null or empty you should return 0. You can assume that the array does not contain any null values.

To receive credit implement insertion sort as described in class. Have the sorted part start at the beginning of the array and grow to the right. Each each step take the left-most value from the unsorted part of the array and move it leftward, swapping elements until it is in the right place. Note that you should not swap equal values. This will both make your sort unstable and cause you to fail the test. When you are finished the array should be sorted and you should return the count of swaps required.

As a reminder, first.compareTo(second) returns a positive value if first is larger than second, a negative value if first is smaller than second, and 0 if they are equal.

// Define a class.

```
public class InsertionSorter {
    int sort(Comparable ray[]){
        if(ray==null||ray.length==1){
            return 0;
        }
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<ray.length-1;i++) {
            int c=i+1;

            int r=i;

            while(ray[r].compareTo(ray[c])>0){
                Comparable second=ray[c];
                Comparable first=ray[r];
                ray[c]=first;
                ray[r]=second;
                count++;
                if(r==0) {
                    break;
                }
                r--;
                c--;
            }

        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

And the errors:

```
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:47: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
    Assert.assertEquals(InsertionSorter.sort(null), 0, "Incorrect result for null array:");
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:49: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
    Assert.assertEquals(InsertionSorter.sort(new Integer[] { }), 0, "Incorrect result for empty array:");
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:52: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
    Assert.assertEquals(InsertionSorter.sort(yourArray), 0, "Incorrect result for single-item array:");
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:58: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
    Assert.assertEquals(InsertionSorter.sort(yourArray), 0, "Incorrect result for small sorted array:");
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:64: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
    Assert.assertEquals(InsertionSorter.sort(yourArray), 1, "Incorrect result for small unsorted array:");
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:79: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
        int yourCount = InsertionSorter.sort(yourValues);
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:94: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
        int yourCount = InsertionSorter.sort(yourValues);
                                       ^
src/test/java/InsertionSorterTest.java:109: error: non-static method sort(Comparable[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
        int yourCount = InsertionSorter.sort(yourValues);
                                       ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update you question with the complete code to get the exact solution. The given error happens when you try to call a non-static method from a static context. That means given method sort is defined as non static, and you are trying to call this method from a static method. may be your public static `main` function(), you can resolve this either declare method as: `public static int sort()` or create `InsertionSorter` class object on to access to sort function. How to declare it depends on your need.

Comment: Yeah the problem here is I cannot access the public static main function () since the test cases are hidden by the website. But the "public static int sort()" truly works, thanks a lot